# how do I set the channel image in an RSS feed created with Zend_Feed_Writer?

Tags: zend-framework, rss

I can't find any setImage method.

Using Zend Framework 1.10.2 (1.10.3 was released today, but I didn't see any mention of Zend_Feed_Writer at all in the changelog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there was no such functionality in 1.10.3.
I opened a ticket for it, and such functionality was added for 1.10.5